# GeoServer GWC seeding in 900913 slower than 4326

Tags: geoserver, tiles, ubuntu, geowebcache, wmts

Using the integrated GeoWebCahce for GeoServer, I am trying to create a tiled cache for a layergroup and having a problem when trying to seed in EPSG:900913.
Even after increasing both the minimal and maximal heapsize and making sure marlin renderer is enabled seeding for EPSG:900913 only works for me in one process at a time and a very slow process at that.

For example I currently have a cache for levels 1:14 but when i try to seed level 15 (~200,00 tiles for my area), then I can only seed with one process or all my processes end prematurely (like described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119028/geoserver-geowebcache-seeding-dies-prematurely).), But if I use EPSG:4326 with no pre-existing cache for all those levels (1:15, ~950,000 tiles) then I can use multiple processes and finish all of them in a few hours.

The EPSG:900913 tiles seed at a rate of ~100-200 every 15 minutes, this is very wierd for me but I need them too.
What else might I be able to do?

I am using an Ubuntu Server 16.04 VM on a windows host with 6GB RAM, GeoServer 2.14 Snapshot.

Comment: is your underlying data stored as 4326?

Comment: Not specificaly, some in 4326, some in 900913 and some in EPSG:2039. All are stored in the same PostGIS Database. most of the data is stored in 2039 but publishe to geoserver with a reprojection to 900913.